# Why is addTreeModelListener() not working?

Tags: java, tree

The following code results in no Listeners being added to the tree (empty list):

```
CustomTreeModel model = (CustomTreeModel) jTree_ATree.getModel();
model.addTreeModelListener(new CustomTreeModelListener(jTree_ATree, CustomTreeModelListener.InsertionAction.EXPAND));

System.out.println("LISTENERS:");
for (CustomTreeModelListener listener : model.getListeners(CustomTreeModelListener.class)) {
    System.out.println(listener);
}
```

Notes:

- My CustomTreeModel `extends` Java's DefaultTreeModel, and does not override any method related to listeners.
- My CustomTreeModelListener `implements` TreeModelListener and, with exception to the interface methods (`treeNodesChanged`, `treeNodesInserted`, etc), also doesn't override anything.

Why is the listener not being added to the TreeModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listeners are not stored by their actual class, but by the listener interface they implement. So to get your listener, use `model.getListeners(TreeModelListener.class)`. This is also explained in the JavaDoc of [`DefaultTreeModel.getListener(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getListeners%28java.lang.Class%29):

> Returns an array of all the objects currently registered as *Foo*Listeners upon this model. *Foo*Listeners are registered using the add*Foo*Listener method.

It’s also obvious if you have a look at the source code of [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel-source.html):

```
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) 
{
    listenerList.add(TreeModelListener.class, listener);
}

public <T extends EventListener> T[] getListeners(Class<T> listenerType)
{
    return listenerList.getListeners(listenerType);
}
```

Comment: Ok...God news: The problem isn't the listener not being registered. Bad news: The listener doesn't seem to be listening, and I have no idea why...

Comment: @TheLima hmm, I guess we won’t solve this new problem without further information. Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Well, without knowing where the problem is, I can't reproduce it, and so can't make a MCV example; At least not without the complete project. I know it's not ideal, but I'm currently redoing the whole thing from scratch to try and fix it. If that fails I don't think I have any other reasonable choice, than to upload to GitHub and post a link here. Maybe I'm doing some other error out of ignorance about a detail, like what you answered, and someone who knows about it might help me spot it. --- I spent the last two days hunting for this bug with no success...I'm beginning to get desperate... =(